# MVC @Html.Grid Column Height Adjustment

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to display a small section of text from an otherwise large block to act as "context clues". I am able to adjust the width of the column however I cannot figure out how to adjust the height, or amount of lines that get displayed. Code is below:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false)
          .RenderValueAs(model => 
                 @Html.ActionLink(model.Name, "Details", new { id = model.Id }));
   columns.Add(model => model.Description).Titled("Description").Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).SetWidth(350);
   columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).SetWidth(15)
          .RenderValueAs(model =>
                 <a class=\"btn btn-mini\" href=\"/LaborCategory/Edit/" + model.Id + "\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"/></a>");
   columns.Add().Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).SetWidth(15)
          .RenderValueAs(model =>
                 <a class=\"btn btn-mini\" href=\"/LaborCategory/Delete/" + model.Id + "\"><i class=\"icon-trash\"/></a>");
}).Sortable(true).Filterable().WithPaging(20)
```

The particular line in question is the second columns.add line for "description". I don't want the text field to be clickable, just display the text and truncate after "x" # of lines, characters, or whatever else I use to make this work

thanks in advance

Solution:

I used inline CSS styling. You have to wrap the  tag in a  otherwise it won't work..

```
.RenderValueAs(model => "<div style='white-space:nowrap; width: 350px; height:50px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;'>"+model.Description+"</div>")
```

Comment: Set the height in your stylesheet. You can assign a css class to each column.

Comment: You're right ended up using inline styling, thanks!